# InfiniteScroll and Custom Behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, infinite-scroll

I'm using http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/ to provide the infinitescroll functionality, however the default settings of the plugin relies on the href attribute of the next link to detect the current page and ajaxily load the next set of results.

I am already keeping track of the result offset and pagesize in my own javascript objects and just want the infinitescroll plugin to call the window.LoadMore function to load the next results, I checked the plugin code and it looks like i should override the loading.start function(the beginAjax specifically) ,

```
        opts.loading.start = opts.loading.start || function() {

            $(opts.navSelector).hide();
            opts.loading.msg
                .appendTo(opts.loading.selector)
                .show(opts.loading.speed, function () {
                    beginAjax(opts);
            });
        };
```

is this the right function to override? , and if yes how would i do this from the plugin initialization, the below code won't work

```
        ($('.deals-list'), this.el).infinitescroll({
            navSelector  : "div.navigation",
            nextSelector : "div.navigation a",
            itemSelector : ".deal",
            debug: true,
            loading.start: function(){
                alert('testing');
            }
        });
```

Thanks.

Yehia

Answer (score 1):

Infinite scroll provides custom behaviors. To create a new behavior to solve your particular problem, you have to do two things.

First, extend infinitescroll's prototype, and define a custom retrieve method:

```
$.extend($.infinitescroll.prototype, {
    retrieve_custombehavior: function () {
        $('#nav > a').click();
    }
});
```

notice the method's suffix, `_custombehavior`. This will be the behavior that we'll pass into infinite-scroll (i.e. the method collection it will look for when determining it's actions - in this case `retrieve_custombehavior`).

Second, pass the behavior suffix into infinite scroll's constructor:

```
$('.deals-list').infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : "div.navigation",
    nextSelector : "div.navigation a",
    itemSelector : ".deal",
    debug: true,
    behavior: '_custombehavior'
});
```

This causes infinite-scroll to run your custom behavior once it reaches the end of the page (and the retrieve method is called)

Answer (score 0):

Not super familiar with the infinite scroll function so I can't speak on whether that's the correct function to override.  Just a glance says it probably is.

Try this:

```
($('.deals-list'), this.el).infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : "div.navigation",
    nextSelector : "div.navigation a",
    itemSelector : ".deal",
    debug: true,
    loading: { 
        start: function(){
            alert('testing');
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is custom Solution. i am using it

```js
(function($, undefined) {
 $.extend($.infinitescroll.prototype,{
  _setup_loadOffers: function infscr_setup_loadOffers () {
   var opts = this.options,
   instance = this;
   // Bind nextSelector link to retrieve
   $('a.btn-seemore-offers').click(function(e) {
    instance.retrieve();
   });
   
  },
 });
})(jQuery);
$('#container').infinitescroll({behavior: 'loadOffers',})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a library for your work, you can try to write from scratch. All you need is to decide your cell(page) that will be loaded one by one at the end of the screen. And you can store their `offset().top` values in javascript. Then you will need a `pageRecognition()` method that will run on every scroll. In that method, you run on `pageCluster` list that holds a dictionary that has page-index and it's `offset().top` values.
You can compare window.scrollTop() and these offset.top() values of pages to recognize which page is on.

In this way, you do not need to follow any update from any library. At a professional level, it's also recommended.